# Apple Subscription - Detecting subscription cancelation state

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-subscription, receipt-validation

We built an analytics system for our messaging using the IAP receipts Apple provides us and one use case for us is to be able to segment users with   expired subscription.

While doing that we have discovered that some users have `expiration_date` in the past (usually only couple of hours ago) and `auto_renew_status` is "1" (true) but the `is_in_billing_retry_period` is "0". I couldn't find what this state means, does anyone have an idea of how to interpret this state?

The documentation says Apple is trying to bill the user 24hours prior the expiration date an if there's a billing error the user should get into `is_in_billing_retry_period` = "1".

Answer (score -1):

`is_in_billing_retry_period: "0"` is an indicator for an expired subscription that Apple has stopped attempting to renew the subscription.

You should see an `expiration_intent: 2` as well indicating the subscription expired due to a billing error.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html)